# Creating Proc returns a 1064/42000 error on END statement

Tags: mysql, procedure

So I was trying to create this procedure where I check if the data exists and insert the values into both tables if don't.

But when I run the code I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 40. Error 1064. SQLSTATE 42000

Here is the procedure code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRI_NEW_CLI(
    IN TELEFONE VARCHAR(20),
    IN EMAIL VARCHAR(50),
    IN CPF VARCHAR(11),
    IN SENHA VARCHAR(255),
    IN NOME VARCHAR(255),
    IN SOBRENOME VARCHAR(255),
    OUT NEW_ID INT,
    OUT C_ERR VARCHAR(5),
    OUT T_ERR VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN    
newcli:BEGIN

    IF EXISTS( SELECT (1) FROM USERS u WHERE u.T_URS_TEL = TELEFONE ) THEN
        SET C_ERR = '10001';
        SET T_ERR = 'TELEFONE EXISTENTE NA BASE DE DADOS';
        LEAVE newcli;
    END IF;

    IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM USERS u WHERE u.T_USR_EMAIL = EMAIL) THEN
        SET C_ERR = '10002';
        SET T_ERR = 'EMAIL EXISTENTE NA BASE DE DADOS';
        LEAVE newcli;
    END IF;

    IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM F_USERS f WHERE f.T_DOC_CPF = CPF) THEN
        SET C_ERR = "10003";
        SET T_ERR = "CPF EXISTENTE NA BASE DE DADOS";
        LEAVE newcli;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO USERS (T_USR_EMAIL, T_URS_TEL, T_USR_PASS, F_TYPE)
    SELECT EMAIL, TELEFONE, MD5(SENHA), 'C';

    SET NEW_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO F_USERS (USER_ID, T_FIRSTNAME, T_LASTNAME, T_DOC_CPF)
    SELECT NEW_ID, NOME, SOBRENOME, CPF;
END newcli;
END;
```

`
The code I made was trying to fix the same error in different positions, but now I can't tell how to make it works.

I tested the inserts into isolated cases and it worked just fine, but I don't know why I keeping those "default" error messages where nothing can be told.

EDIT:

I did it with `IF..ELSE` statements.

But I still want to understand why I was getting those errors and how (if possible) could I do it more or less the way it's written.

Thanks for your help, guys.

Comment: Usually a good idea is to comment stuff out until it works then start add stuff back gradually until it breaks. This finds the mistake

Comment: I believe it's the labeled `BEGIN..END` that is givin' me the error, since I managed once to do it when it was only one parameter to validate (`IF EXISTS`), but I'll try to comment the stuff

Comment: I commented the `INSERT`s and it gave me the same error

Comment: Why not just leave the first if statement in and work from there

Comment: I wanted to tell when the case was different, but this may works for now... let me test it

Comment: is it really your intention to bail out and not do inserts on certain conditions?

Comment: My intention is just to not insert if it meets the conditions, and give the message based on the meet condition.

Comment: Right. And you would have had to implement a LOOP strategy to do LEAVE. And you had no intention of doing an `ITERATE` so the whole construct would have been confuzzled for the next guy trying to debug/understand the mindset that put it together.

Comment: So you are telling me that `LEAVE` is only for loops? what should I use to leave the procedure?

Comment: blocks of logic like your answer that force a drop out. Oh for the days of the BASIC `goto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I could not find out why it was giving that error.

I changed the code and it worked.

But I'm still interested to make the code works into the way I wrote it.

Here the new code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRI_NEW_CLI(
    IN TELEFONE VARCHAR(20),
    IN EMAIL VARCHAR(50),
    IN CPF VARCHAR(11),
    IN SENHA VARCHAR(255),
    IN NOME VARCHAR(255),
    IN SOBRENOME VARCHAR(255),
    OUT NEW_ID INT,
    OUT C_ERR VARCHAR(5),
    OUT T_ERR VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN    

    IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT (1) FROM USERS u WHERE u.T_URS_TEL = TELEFONE ) THEN
        IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT (1) FROM USERS u WHERE u.T_USR_EMAIL = EMAIL) THEN
            IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT (1) FROM F_USERS f WHERE f.T_DOC_CPF = CPF) THEN

                INSERT INTO USERS (T_USR_EMAIL, T_URS_TEL, T_USR_PASS, F_TYPE)
                SELECT EMAIL, TELEFONE, MD5(SENHA), 'C';

                SET NEW_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

                INSERT INTO F_USERS (USER_ID, T_FIRSTNAME, T_LASTNAME, T_DOC_CPF)
                SELECT NEW_ID, NOME, SOBRENOME, CPF;

            ELSE
                SET C_ERR = "10003";
                SET T_ERR = "CPF EXISTENTE NA BASE DE DADOS";
            END IF;
            ELSE
                SET C_ERR = '10002';
                SET T_ERR = 'EMAIL EXISTENTE NA BASE DE DADOS';
            END IF;
    ELSE
        SET C_ERR = '10001';
        SET T_ERR = 'TELEFONE EXISTENTE NA BASE DE DADOS';
    END IF;

END;
```